# WPF UserControl weird binding problem

Tags: wpf, listview, binding, user-controls

Im usign a Ribbon Window and in the "content area beneath" I have a grid in which I will be displaying UserControls. To demonstrate my problem lets take a look at this simple UserControl:

```
        <ListView x:Name="lvPersonList">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Width="120" Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Width="120" Header="Height" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Height}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

And the code:

```
public partial class MyUserControl: UserControl
{
    private List<Person> personList;

    public TestSnpList()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.personList = new List<Person>();
        this.personList.Add(new Person { Name = "Chuck Norris", Height = 210 });
        this.personList.Add(new Person { Name = "John Rambo", Height = 200 });
        this.lvPersonList.ItemsSource = personList;
    }
}
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
}
```

The parent Window:

```
    <Grid x:Name="grdContent" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <controls:MyUserControl x:Name="myUserControl" Visibility="Visible"/>
    </Grid>
```

I don't understant why this binding doesn't work. Instead of values (Name and Height) I get full class names. If I use this code in a Window it works fine.

Any ideas? I would like this user contorl works for itself (it gets the data form the DB and represents it in a ListView)...

Thanks!

Comment: Can you say what `public TestSnpList()` is? Are you able to reach the code `this.lvPersonList.ItemsSource = personList;` using debugger. `I get full class names` Do you get the class name Person?

Comment: Ah sorry, this TestSnpList is a real class name (I renamed it here and I forgot to rename the constructor).

Yes sure I can reach it - it has 2 items (myNamespace.Person).

When listView is rendered I can see two items like this:
myNamespace.Person
myNamespace.Person

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem is with RibbonWindow.
If I use Window and UserControl binding works fine, but if I use RibbonWindow (Odyssey Ribbon) binding doesn't work. What I don't understand is that in design mode I can see proper values and in running mode I see only class names:

http://i977.photobucket.com/albums/ae255/HekoSLO/designModeVSrunning.png